# How to create a HashSet from a Set?

Tags: java, hibernate

There is a foreign key in my entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "role_code")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "role_lib")
    private String lib;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "role_menu" , joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_code")} , inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "menu_id")} )
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Menu> menus = new HashSet<Menu>();

    // getters and setters

}
```

It is said in Hibernate documentation that relationship attributes should be of type `Interface`. Now my problem is when dealing with an instance of this class and using the `getMenus()` method :

```
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Set<Menu> getListMenu(String role_code) {

        return ((Role)get(role_code)).getMenus();

    }
```

I want to cast it to a HashSet , but I got castException of persistent object at runtime. So how to make it to be `HashSet` ?

Comment: `new HashSet(obj.getMenus());` and you have yourself a HashSet from a Set. But I agree with @Todd that you rather don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot cast if the implementations of `Set` is not `HashSet`. But you can create a object:

```
new HashSet(obj.getMenus);
```

But it's always better to use interfaces, not the implementation.

Here is a note from [Hibernate doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html):

> Hibernate will actually replace the HashSet with an instance of
>   Hibernate's own implementation of Set. Be aware of the following
>   errors:
>
> ......
>
> (HashSet) cat.getKittens(); // Error!

And here is why you don't actually need to cast nor to create a new object:

> The persistent collections injected by Hibernate behave like HashMap,
>   HashSet, TreeMap, TreeSet or ArrayList, depending on the interface
>   type.

Comment: HashSet has a O(1) algorithm complexity , this is the reason :)

Comment: Are you sure the implementation given to you by Hibernate is not performing to your standards? If you don't have a failing test, don't try to fix it.

Comment: Totally agree with @C-Otto. Remember: [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization). :)